# If you use a separator in a swift/firebase project, how do you make two childs from the component?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

Say when a user enters an email(jake@aol.com), you want that to become child1 (Jake) and child2(@aol.com).

```
                    ///here would be if whole email is added 
databaseRef.child("users").child(userID).child("postID").setValue(userID)
```

.

```
///here would be making them into components
                    let components = self.emailField.text!.split(separator: "@")
                    components.forEach { print($0) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split separates the string into two components (in this case) and stores them in an array

```
components[0] = name
components[1] = domain
```

and omits the separator @ sign. So the array components, index 0 would be 'jake' and index 1 would be 'aol.com'.

So you could write

```
let components = self.emailField.text!.split(separator: "@")
let child1 = components[0] //will be jake
let child2 = components[1] //will be aol.com
```

Some docs on [Split](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2894564-split) and [Arrays](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array)

Be very careful unwrapping optionals with ! as if it's nil, it will crash your code. Always safely work with optionals through guard, if let or a nil coalescing operator ??

Comment: Thanks. Pretty sure ! is safe there because if the email field is not valid, it never gets to this part of the code.